# How to set an IP for my domain programmatically in my APP

Tags: java, android, dns

How to set an ip for my domain programmatically in my APP?

1. set an ip for my domain if the DNS Lookup failed.
2. update the ip for my domain when DNS Loopup succeed, and save this IP for later use.

The server side use domain name for virtual hosts map, so I can't use IP directly.
edit `/etc/hosts works`, but I need change it programmatically without root.

this code worked on java, what's the way on android?

```
 url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/");//is this no DNS lookup at all?
 System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");//'Host' head don't work without this
 conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.mydomain.com");
```